# Pagination buttons triggering ajax even when disabled - dataTable Server-side Paging

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a data table initialized with server-side paging which is working fine. However the problem is with the disabled "Next" and "Last" buttons in the last page, which on click are showing up "Processing..." message. Most likely on-click hey are triggering unwanted ajax event.

Here is my code:

```
function initTestTable(){
    myTable = $('#testTable').dataTable({
    scrollY:        "168px",
    scrollCollapse: false,
    jQueryUI:       true,
    bRetrieve : true,
    bDestroy : true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bSearch":false,
    bFilter: false, 
    bInfo: false,
    "sPaginationType": "input",               
    "bLengthChange" : true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "testTableData.html",
        "type": "GET",
    },
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 0,
        "data": "code",
        "render": function ( data, type, full ) {
            return '<a href="'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
          }
      },
      {
        "targets": 1,
        "data": "description",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return data;
        }
      }]
  });
 }
```

Please let me know if there is a way to stop this.

Comment: Your code is similar to [server-side processing example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) but I don't see the behavior you're describing. What version of DataTables are you using (the latest is 1.10.7)? Can you share a link to your page or create an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: @Gyrocode - I do have many other options which I removed to keep my code listing small & simple. Sorry for that. Here are the other options I am using:    
               ` scrollCollapse: false,
                jQueryUI:       true,
                "processing" : true,
                bRetrieve : true,
                bDestroy : true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bSearch":false,
                bFilter: false, 
                bInfo: false,
               "sPaginationType": "input",`

Comment: @Gyrocode - I have edited my question to add all the options. Please have a look. Verrsion I am using is - DataTables 1.10.5

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your problem using [Navigation with text input](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) pagination plug-in, it doesn't even appear in server-side processing mode.

However, your code works when `"sPaginationType": "input"` is removed or replaced with one of the default modes, for example `"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"`.

Consider updating to the latest version of DataTables (1.10.7) and switching from [Navigation with text input](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) pagination plug-in to one of the default pagination modes or another pagination plug-in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // AJAX emulation for demonstration only
  $.mockjax({
      url: '/test/0',
      responseTime: 200,
      response: function(settings){
         this.responseText = {
            draw: settings.data.draw,
            data: [
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
              [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", 61, "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ]
            ],
            recordsTotal: 1000,
            recordsFiltered: 1000
         };
      }
  });

  $('#example').dataTable({    
    "scrollY":        "168px",
    "scrollCollapse": false,
    "jQueryUI":       true,
    "bRetrieve" : true,
    "bDestroy" : true,

    "bPaginate": true,
    "bSearch":false,
    "bFilter": false, 
    "bInfo": false,
        
    //"sPaginationType": "input",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bLengthChange" : true,        
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/test/0",
        "type": "GET"
    }    
  });
      
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/pagination/input.js"></script>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```